# Is it possible to store sets persistently in pinia?

Tags: vue.js, set, pinia

I would like to define pinia store which stores a set like this:

```js
type Hi = {h: Set<string>}
const useHi = defineStore("hi", { state: (): Hi => ({h: new Set<string>()})
```

I am using a persistent store plugin. Namely, this one: https://github.com/iendeavor/pinia-plugin-persistedstate-2

However, when I use the h attribute of the store I do get a set but when I do this:

```
hi = useHi()
hi.h.has("21")
```

I get `hi.h.has is not a function`.

I think that pinia tries to serialize the set and then it gets `{}` so it thinks it is just an empty object. Is there any way you can store sets in pinia state?

Comment: It's totally up to how this specific plugin works, and you can check this in source code. It's safe to assume that it doesn't handle sets. Just don't use anything that won't work well with JSON.stringify because this is what such plugins will most likely use. You can write your own plugin or fork an existing one if you really need this.

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense now that you say it. It is not pinia that implements this. If you make this an answer I will choose it.